# Search for columns ending with certain pattern, then delete that column

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed, grep

I need to search a line of numbers for any columns that end with 999 and then delete that entire column while preserving any leading number (i.e. 8599999.... --> 85)

**Data Line:**

```
66 72 79 84 87 90 91 92 92 93 92 91 89 85999999999999999999999999999999999
```

**Desired Output:**

```
66 72 79 84 87 90 91 92 92 93 92 91 89 85
```

Comment: what if a column has `9999` or `7999` ?

Comment: The data will always be appended with `9999999, etc`

Comment: @AaronPerry that didn't answer @spasic's question though. More importantly, can other columns than the last one end in `999`? Can any column contain `999` then other digits (e.g. `1299934`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ s='66 72 79 84 87 90 91 92 92 93 92 91 89 85999999999999999999999999999999999'

$ # POSIX sed
$ echo "$s" | sed 's/999\{1,\}//g'
66 72 79 84 87 90 91 92 92 93 92 91 89 85

$ # sed with ERE support
$ echo "$s" | sed -E 's/999+//g'
66 72 79 84 87 90 91 92 92 93 92 91 89 85

$ # with GNU sed
$ echo "$s" | sed 's/999\+//g'
66 72 79 84 87 90 91 92 92 93 92 91 89 85
```

This deletes all occurrences of `99` followed by one or more `9` anywhere in the line

See also: [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: You need to anchor that with `/999\+$/` or you'll turn `85999123` into `85123` the first time it occurs on the line.

Comment: well, question said `any column`.. and there are other cases like you point out.. if OP clarifies, I'll change accordingly

Comment: no, it won't remove succeeding columns.. only particular sequence of 999 followed by any number of 9s, anywhere in the line gets deleted.. for ex: `echo '66 7999 :9999: 99' | sed 's/999\+//g'` gives `66 7 :: 99`

Answer (score 1):

In AWK:

```
awk '{gsub(/999+$/,"")}1' test.in
```

Let's see:

```
$ cat > test.in
1 2 3
4 5 69999999
$ awk '{gsub(/999+$/,"")}1' test.in
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

Comment: You're only doing 1 substitution so that should be `sub()` instead of `gsub()` but more importantly that will delete any line that doesn't end in `999+`. To avoid surprises like that, only use the result of an action as a condition if it's required and you've thought through all of the consequences, otherwise use `{action}1` instead of `action`.

Comment: Lol, so it seems. Fixed. Thanks for pointing it out. Too many edits in too short time.

Answer (score 1):

with `sed`;

```
sed  -e 's/999\+$//' data.txt
```

Comment: That will delete from the first `999` to the end of the line, not a chain of 3 or more 9s at the end of a line as required.